# Why does each successive term in a Taylor series need to be much less than the previous term?

Tags: taylor-expansion

This is an extension to [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552036/how-do-you-taylor-expand-the-log-likelihood-function-of-the-poisson-distribution) for this [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548297/how-do-you-sketch-the-poisson-distribution-function-l-mun-frac-mune) asked by myself:

> When doing a maximum likelihood fit, we often take a ‘Gaussian
>   approximation’. This problem works through the case of a measurement from a Poisson distribution. The Poisson distribution results in a likelihood for the average number $\mu$, given that $n$ events were observed:$L(\mu;n)=\cfrac{\mu^{n}e^{-\mu}}{n!}$.
>
> We need to write this in the form 
>   $$L(\mu;n)\approx L_0 e^{-\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2n}}$$ 
>   $\mu_0$ is defined to be the value of $\mu$ which gives the maximum of the likelihood, at which the likelihood has a value $L_0$.

---

Taking the natural logarithm of $L$ gives

$$\ln(L) = \ln(\mu^n)+\ln(e^{-\mu})-\ln(n!)=n\ln(\mu)-\mu - \ln(n!)$$

and taking the derivative gives

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}=\color{maroon}{\frac{n}{\mu}-1}$$

The maximum is given when $(2)$ is equal to zero; so $\mu_0$ satisfies
$$\frac{n}{\mu_0}-1=0\implies \mu_0=n$$

Therefore $$\ln(L_0)=n\ln(n) - n -\ln(n!)$$

Performing a Taylor expansion up to the second order of $\ln(L)$ around the maximum, where $\mu_0=n$, is

$$\ln(L)\approx\ln(L_0) + \frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\bigg|_{\mu=n}(\mu-n) + \frac{\mathrm{d^2}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu^2}\bigg|_{\mu=n}\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2!}$$

Taking the second derivative gives

$$\frac{\mathrm{d^2}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu^2}=\color{#180}{-\frac{n}{\mu^2}}\tag{1}$$

Hence, to second order

$$\ln(L)\approx \ln(L_0) \color{blue}{- \frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2n}}$$

$$\implies \frac{L}{L_0}\approx e^{-\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2n}}\implies \fbox{$\color{red}{L(\mu;n)\approx L_0 e^{-\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2n}}}$}\tag{2}$$

---

The Gaussian approximation therefore comes down to neglecting the third order and
higher terms. The first neglected term in the Taylor expansion is third order.

Evaluating this derivative gives 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d^3}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu^3}=\color{#F80}{\frac{2n}{\mu^3}}$$
Hence, the first neglected term is
$$\frac{\mathrm{d^3}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu^3}\bigg|_{\mu=n}\frac{(\mu-n)^3}{3!}=\frac{2}{n^2}\frac{(\mu-n)^3}{6}=\frac{(\mu-n)^3}{3n^2}$$

For the approximation to be valid, this must be much smaller than the second order term, so

$$\fbox{$\color{purple}{\frac{(\mu-n)^3}{3n^2}\ll\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2n}}$}\tag{???}$$

I have **two** simple questions regarding the expression marked $\color{purple}{\mathrm{purple}}$ since the second order term shown earlier in $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ is negative: $\color{blue}{-\cfrac{(\mu-n)^2}{2n}}$. So the $\color{purple}{\mathrm{purple}}$ inequality cannot possibly be true.

However, assuming for my first question that we are only concerned with the *magnitude* (neglecting the negative sign); Why does the third order term need to be $\ll$ second order term? On what grounds is this necessary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first neglected term
should be smaller
*in magnitude*,
so that
$\big|\frac{(\mu-n)^3}{3n^2}\big|
\ll \big|\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2n}\big|
$
or
$|\mu-n|
\ll \frac32 n
$.

Comment: Excellent, that has answered my first question; Now can you please explain to me why the third order term needs to be $\ll$ second order term? Thank you.

Comment: That's so the first two terms are a good approximation to the actual sum.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm gonna make a partial try, not sure at all that this is a fruitful approach, please feel free to point out anything fishy.

If a function is bounded on an interval or a set and has a Taylor expansion there, if we were not sure that new monomial terms had coefficients smaller than the previous at least such that $c_{k+1} \leq k xc_k$ for the $x$ in the area of convergence then the value could increase without bounds but that can not be because the function does not. Which $k$ would be sufficient for the series to diverge?

Comment: Thanks for your reply (+1), this was going to be a prime candidate for a 'tumbleweed' badge otherwise :) I'm glad that someone has taken the time to answer, I have to leave this open for a bit more input first though, thank you